# Getting the contact in salesforce

Tags: apex, email

From Inbound email message, how can I get the sender name of the email? For example:

```
case.ContactId = email.fromName;
```

Comment: I have a question if I am in Case how can I get the Contact Name using apex?

Comment: Please edit your original post to describe your use case and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you'll need to query from the database:

```
Contact[] matchingContacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :email.fromName];
if(matchingContacts.size() > 0) {
  incomingCase.ContactId = matchingContacts[0].Id;
}
```

Personally, though, I'd recommend trying to match by email address, if possible.

```
Contact[] matchingContcts = [FIND :email.fromAddress IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id)][0];
if(matchingContacts.size() > 0) {
  incomingCase.ContactId = matchingContacts[0].Id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this help me a lot. I have a question if I am in Case how can I get the Contact Name using apex?

Comment: For example incomingCase.ContactId i would like to get the Name of Contact incomingCase.NameofContact

Comment: Do I need to Iterate the case and contact? how do i do that sorry please help

Comment: @JohnSmith Presumably, yes, you'd need to do some iteration, but without seeing more than a single line of code, it's hard to tell where you're getting hung up.

Comment: if(toAddresses.size()>0){
             System.debug('Inside the to Addresses.size');
             incomingCase.Description = email.plainTextBody;
             incomingCase.Subject = email.subject;
             incomingCase.Status= 'New'; 
             incomingCase.RecordTypeId = caseComplaintRecordType;
             incomingCase.Origin ='Support Email';       
             //incomingCase.ContactId = matchingContacts[0].Id;  -> I want to get the Contact 
   
            }

Comment: @JohnSmith Like I said, you'll need to search or query for the contact you're interested in. My example only shows one record (as in your original question), but you could aggregate the queries together.